# Accessing the member of a structure by double pointer of that structure type

Tags: c

I have a structure `Item` with the following members.

```c
struct Item{
    char *name;
    int price;
    double weight;
};
```

Another structure `Inventory` with the following members.

```c
struct Inventory{
    struct Item **item;
    int NUMITEMS;
};
```

I have a function `addItem()` which takes the `Inventory*` as its parameter.

```c
void addItem(struct Inventory* i){
     printf("Enter Name:");
     scanf("%s",i->item->name);
     printf("Enter Price");
     scanf("%d",i->item->price);
     printf("Enter Weight");
     scanf("%lf",i->item->weight);
}
```

The main objective of the function is to assign the values to the member of Item structure. How can I do so? I want to set the values of the members of the Item structure through the double pointer of type item from a function.
My entire code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 struct Item{
  char *name;
  int price;
  double weight;
   };

 struct Inventory{
  struct Item **item;
  int NUMITEMS;
 }inventory1;

struct Character{
 char *name;
 int Level;
 long XP;
 struct Inventory inventory;
 };
  void createCharacter(struct Character* c){
    printf("Enter Name:");
    c->name = (char*) malloc(40*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",c->name);
    printf("Enter Level:");
    scanf("%d",&c->Level);
    printf("Enter XP:");
   scanf("%ld",&c->XP);
  }
void viewCharacter(struct Character* b){
printf("%s level %d with %ld XP",b->name,b->Level,b->XP);
  }
 void addItem(struct Inventory* i){
 i->item =(struct Item*)malloc(i->NUMITEMS*sizeof(struct Item));
 printf("Enter name:");
 scanf("%s",i->item->(*name));
 }

void viewItem(struct Inventory* i){
   //yet to write
 }
```

Comment: Function `addItem` is plain wrong. Furthermore what is the reason for the double indirection in inventory. With no information on it, I cannot help.

Comment: i->tem->name and all other below are a syntactical error.

Comment: We need a more elaborate explanation of what you are trying to do in order to help you. Like what is the purpose of the member variable NUMITEMS. Is it counting the items in the inventory or does it represent the maximum number of items possible in the inventory? What is it what you are trying to accomplish in general with this code?

Comment: @josepchappa actually i am doing my assignment and encounter the error.yes NUMITEM is to count the number of items in inventory

Comment: If you are storing an array of `Item`s in your `Inventory`, why do you need a pointer to pointer in the array?  How are you allocating the data pointed at by `item` in `Inventory`?  Most likely you should just be using `struct Item *items;` inside `struct Inventory`.  If you must have a pointer to pointer (note that 'double pointer' is convenient, but ambiguous in general — both `struct Item **item` and `double *ptr` are 'double pointers'), you need to show how it is supposed to be used — because we can't say from the information given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure ...

> ```
>  struct Inventory{
>   struct Item **item;
>   int NUMITEMS;
>  }inventory1;
> ```

... has the appearance of a wrapper for an array, perhaps dynamically allocated, of pointers to `struct Item`.  Instances' `item` members point to the first *pointer* in that array.  There is more than one way that the members of the items pointed to by the array elements can be accessed, but since the structure represents an array, the most natural and intuitive way would probably be to use array syntax:

```
struct Inventory *inv = /* ... */ ;

for (int i = 0; i < inv->NUMITEMS; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n",
            // here:
            inv->item[i]->name
    );
}
```

**Explanation**: with `inv` being a pointer to a `struct Inventory`, the indirect member-access operator is natural for accessing its members, such as `inv->item`.  For its part, `inv->item` is a pointer to another pointer.  You have to dereference it and then dereference the result to get to a `struct Item`.  Although you could use the dereferencing operator (unary `*`) directly for that purpose, the array indexing operator `[]` and the indirect member access operator `->` both dereference as part of their behavior (always), so you get the needed two derferencings by indexing into the array of items and using the indirect access operator to get the member of interest.

**Additional notes**:

- the name of the `item` member of `struct Inventory` may be misleading you, both in that it is a pointer to a pointer to an item rather than a pointer directly to an item, and in that it has every appearance of serving as a pointer to *the first of (possibly) several* item pointers in an array of such, despite its name being singular.
- the signature of your `viewItem()` function and maybe also of your `addItem()` function therefore seems to be insufficient for the apparent task.  If you want to view a particular item then you need to specify *which one*, presumably by passing its index as an additional argument.  The same if you want to add an item at a specific position (as opposed to appending after the last item already present).

Comment: will it be a dynamic memory allocation?I actually dont want to input the value of NUMITEM instead want it to increase automatically when the function is called and reallocate the memory according to the need.

Comment: @IcanCode is your question answered?

Comment: @josepchappa no

Comment: @IcanCode if you want to allocate memory dynamically instead of setting a predefined size for you inventory list, then I would suggest a linked list

Comment: @IcanCode, the `item` member in a `struct Inventory` *could* point to dynamically-allocated memory, yes, but it doesn't have to do.  That's under your control.  If you want `addItem()` to automatically add at the end (and to update `NUMITEMS` when it does so) then that is viable and does not seem unreasonable.  If you want lock `viewItem()` to always view the first item or always the last item then that, too, is doable, but it does not not seem as reasonable to me.  In any case, this has nothing directly to do with the question of the appropriate syntax for accessing items.

Comment: @IcanCode, another possibility: did you perhaps want `viewItem()` to take a parameter of type `struct Item *` instead of `struct Inventory *`?